# DJANGO creating categories with sub categories

Tags: python, django

I have come unstuck with a categories table I am trying to implement. I am building a project with multiple category levels but what I want to do is build a multi tier category structure.

For example I have created the class with categories as below but I would like to achieve multi level categories as per example below

Action > (+)
       Thriller or Boxing or Gang Related

Any thoughts ?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = (
        ('ACT', 'Action'),
        ('THRILLER', 'Thriller'),
        ('COM', 'Comedy'),
        ('WEST', 'Western'),
        ('MILITARY', 'Military'),
    )

    image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=CATEGORIES
    )
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your model like below. We should use "Parent Child Relation" to achieve your goal.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = (
        ('ACT', 'Action'),
        ('THRILLER', 'Thriller'),
        ('COM', 'Comedy'),
        ('WEST', 'Western'),
        ('MILITARY', 'Military'),
    )

    image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=CATEGORIES
    )
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name="childs")
```

## Examples to access parent and childs:

```
parents = Category.objects.filter(parent=None)
parent =  parents[0] # create some categories before using it
childs = parent.childs.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a tagging package : https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/tagging/

For what you are doing I've used both tagit and tagulous. Both are fine.